# How can I add Edge direction in a networkx graph?

Tags: python, graph, networkx

I made a graph. Here I am using G = nx.DiGraph(). But the output graph is not directed. I need a graph which have Edge direction. I am unable to resolve my problem.

***Code:***

```
import networkx as nx
G = nx.DiGraph()
time = [1100,2000,1500]
a = [[1, 2], [1, 3], [2, 3]]
G.add_edges_from(a)

pos=nx.spring_layout(G) 
nx.draw_networkx(G,pos)

edge_labels = ['A', 'B', 'C']
lst = [[1, 2], [1, 3], [2, 3]]

nx.draw_networkx_edge_labels(G,pos,edge_labels=dict(zip(map(tuple,lst), edge_labels)))
nx.draw_networkx_nodes(G, pos, node_size=time[:len(pos)], node_color='Gray', node_shape='o')
G.size(500)
```

How can I add Edge direction?

Comment: The original plot does show the direction (stop right after the `draw_networkx` command).  If you don't redraw the nodes, you'll see it.  However, you've redrawn nodes at the end and made them relatively large.  These are covering up the arrowheads.

Comment: You may be able to fix it by playing with the settings for the arrowheads.  I'm not very familiar with that, so hopefully someone else can help.

Comment: @Joel is correct.  The simplest thing to do is to allow networkx and matplotlib to handle adjusting the position of the arrowheads based on the node size.  To do this, you can pass your `node_size`, `node_color`, and `node_shape` keyword arguments to the original `nx.draw_networkx()` call and just delete the `nx.draw_networkx_nodes()` line.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with the node size, and the direction arrows are hidden under the nodes!
You can either remove the node size, or use annotation to draw the direction arrows:

```
import networkx as nx
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig, ax = plt.subplots()

G = nx.DiGraph()
time = [1100,2000,1500]
a = [[1, 2], [1, 3], [2, 3]]
G.add_edges_from(a)

pos=nx.spring_layout(G) 
nx.draw_networkx(G,pos)

edge_labels = ['A', 'B', 'C']
lst = [[1, 2], [1, 3], [2, 3]]

nx.draw_networkx_edge_labels(G,pos,edge_labels=dict(zip(map(tuple,lst), edge_labels)))
nx.draw_networkx_nodes(G, pos, node_size=time[:len(pos)], node_color='Gray', node_shape='o')

arrow_props = dict(facecolor='red', edgecolor='black', arrowstyle='->', lw=2,)
for edge in lst:
    ax.annotate('', xy=pos[edge[1]], xytext=pos[edge[0]], arrowprops=arrow_props,)

G.size(500)
```

[image]